# Godaddy multiple domain problem

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy

I have godaddy deluxe plan and here is my problem:

I have two domains for example: `e1.com` and `e2.com`. Both are hosted in same hosting plan. First I created a folder for each domain in the root folder and uploaded two web site but when I'm trying to run my sites, the URL for e1 always shows `http://e1.com/e1/` and for e2 it shows `http://e2.com/e2`. Can I avoid showing e1 and e2 folder and only show `http://e1.com` and `http://e2.com`?

Thank you.